# How to add a new object in GeoTools JMapStatusBar

Tags: geotools

In Geotools map viewer example I'm trying to add a new object (ScaleBar) in the lower status bar (under the map window).
I'm trying this:

```
private static JMapStatusBar doCreateDefaultStatusBar(MapPane mapPane) {
    JMapStatusBar statusBar = new JMapStatusBar();

    statusBar.addItem(new JRendererStatusBarItem(mapPane), false, true);
    statusBar.addItem(new JCoordsStatusBarItem(mapPane));
    statusBar.addItem(new JExtentStatusBarItem(mapPane));
    statusBar.addItem(new JCRSStatusBarItem(mapPane));
    statusBar.addItem(new JScaleStatusBarItem(mapPane)); // the new one that causes exception.
    return statusBar;
}
```

JScaleStatusBarItem.java:

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.ReferencedEnvelope;
import org.geotools.jdbcconnection.MainDialog;
import org.geotools.jdbcconnection.geotools.swing.MapPane;
import org.geotools.jdbcconnection.geotools.swing.control.StatusBarItem;
import org.geotools.jdbcconnection.geotools.swing.locale.LocaleUtils;


public class JScaleStatusBarItem extends StatusBarItem {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //This doesn't work
    private static final String COMPONENT_NAME =
                LocaleUtils.getValue("StatusBar", "ScaleBarItemName"); 
    // If I use this instead it works
    //private static final String COMPONENT_NAME =
    //            LocaleUtils.getValue("StatusBar", "ExtentItemName"); 
        private static final JLabel label = new JLabel();
        private int decLen = 0;
        /**
         * Creates a new item to display the extent of the associated map pane.
         *
         * @param mapPane the map pane
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException if {@code mapPane} is {@code null}
         */
        public JScaleStatusBarItem(MapPane mapPane) {
            super(COMPONENT_NAME,false);

            if (mapPane == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("mapPane must not be null");
            }

            setToolTipText("MapScale");
            decLen = JMapStatusBar.DEFAULT_NUM_DECIMAL_DIGITS;
            setLabelFormat();
            label.setFont(JMapStatusBar.DEFAULT_FONT);
            add(label);
        }

        /**
         * Displays Scale.
         *
         * @param extent the map pane extent
         * @param cache whether to cache a copy of {@code extent}
         */
        public static void displayScale(ReferencedEnvelope extent) {
            ImageIcon icon = null;
            Double[] values =  MapScaleCalculator.calculate(MapView.mapFrame.getMapPane().getDisplayArea(), MapView.mapFrame.getMapPane().getBounds().width, MapView.isGeographic );
            double dScale = values[0];
            MapView.currentScale = dScale;
            try {
                MapView.sbg_image = MapView.sbg.getImageAsFileLocation(dScale, 250, MainDialog.Dpi);
                icon = new ImageIcon(MapView.sbg_image);
                icon.getImage().flush();
                label.setIcon(icon);
                label.setText("");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            double width = values[1];
            String skala = String.format("%,8f%n", dScale);
            String enhet = "m";
            if (width > 10000) {
                width = width/1000;
                enhet = "km";
            }
            String w = String.format("%,8f%n", width).split(",")[0];
            w = "Width=" + w + " " + enhet;
            String scale = "Scale 1:" + skala.split(",")[0];
            if (scale == null || scale.isEmpty()) {
                label.setText("Undefined scale");
            }
            if(!MapView.selScale.getSelectedItem().toString().replace("\u00A0", " ").equals(scale.replace("\u00A0", " ")))
                MapView.selScale.getEditor().setItem(scale);;
        }

        @Override
        public void setNumDecimals(int numDecimals) {
            this.decLen = numDecimals;
            setLabelFormat();
        }

        private void setLabelFormat() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append("x=[%.").append(decLen).append("f, ");
            sb.append("%.").append(decLen).append("f] ");
            sb.append("y=[%.").append(decLen).append("f, ");
            sb.append("%.").append(decLen).append("f]");
        }
    }
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.mapview.JMapStatusBar.doCreateDefaultStatusBar(JMapStatusBar.java:166)
at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.mapview.JMapStatusBar.createDefaultStatusBar(JMapStatusBar.java:133)
at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.mapview.JMapFrame.initComponents(JMapFrame.java:539)
at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.mapview.JMapFrame.getToolBar(JMapFrame.java:586)
at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.mapview.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:634)
at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.MainDialog$181.actionPerformed(MainDialog.java:3333)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6635)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6400)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5011)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4843)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key ScaleBarItemName
at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getObject(ResourceBundle.java:564)
at java.base/java.util.ResourceBundle.getString(ResourceBundle.java:521)
at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.geotools.swing.locale.LocaleUtils.getValue(LocaleUtils.java:213)
at org.geotools.jdbcconnection.mapview.JScaleStatusBarItem.<clinit>(JScaleStatusBarItem.java:42)
... 42 more
```

If I, for example, use:

```
LocaleUtils.getValue("StatusBar", "ExtentItemName");
```

instead of:

```
LocaleUtils.getValue("StatusBar", "ScaleBarItemName");
```

in JScaleStatusBarItem it works, but then I have two "Extent" checkboxes in the "Configure status bar items"-menu that points to the two different classes.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The GeoTools swing module uses resource bundles to allow for the internationalisation of the interface. So you will need to either provide a `.properties` file with `ScaleBarItemName` defined in it, or just use a simple `String` there if you don't plan on having international users.